# How to get postgresql to interpret column names from sub-select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query in PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit.

```
SELECT ( 
    SELECT string_agg(trim(cols::text, '()'), ', ') 
    FROM (
        SELECT 'dog.' || column_name 
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name='dog') 
        AS cols
        ) 
FROM dog;
```

This produces the following output once for every row in the dogs table:

```
dog.id, dog.created_date, dog.updated_date, dog.author_id, dog.mother_id, dog.start_date, dog.end_date, dog.session_type_id, dog.note, dog.cancelled, dog.life_phase
```

But the problem is that the outer select query has not dereferenced the column names and interpreted them as column names but rather labeled the column string_agg and spit out the column names once for every row in the dog table.

How do I get postgresql to ensure that the inner select generating the column names is interpreted by the outer select properly?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: The inner query only has a **single** column which is a string value (containing a comma separated list of column names). You can't have dynamic columns in a SQL statement. The number and the names of the columns for a SELECT statement need to be know at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a dynamic SQL. You need a plpgsql function to do that. Example:

```
create or replace function select_dogs()
returns setof dog language plpgsql as $$
declare
    list_of_columns text;
begin
    SELECT string_agg(trim(cols::text, '()'), ', ') 
    INTO list_of_columns
    FROM (
        SELECT 'dog.' || column_name 
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name='dog'
        ) AS cols;
    return query execute format (
        'select %s from dog', list_of_columns);
end $$;

select * from select_dogs();
```

Read more in the documentation: [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: Thank you. The only problem that I see now with the plpgsql is that even though I've gone to all the trouble to specify the fully qualified column names, the result set has stripped the column names of the teble prefix and period separator, so all of that work was essentially rendered useless. Is there a way I can ensure that those fully qualified column names are preserved?

Comment: @DavidWatson: if you want to select all columns from a table then why don't you just use a `select *` and get rid of all the overhead of writing a function that can't return anything different anyway. The function is an overly complicated way of writing just that: `select * from dog`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is part of a much larger pipeline of queries where disambiguation of columns is a problem due to many joins and I need all the columns in the output and I understand the costs. I'm actually surprised that this is not a solved problem. From a usability perspective, fully qualified columns would be a useful thing when there is more than one table in the query. But I realize that usability, unfortunately, is not high on the priority list of most experts in database internals.

Comment: @DavidWatson - I'm afraid that what you want to achieve (in the context of your previous question) is impossible. I can only imagine the solution on client side, as was suggested by Daniel Vérité.

Comment: @DavidWatson: Why don't you create a view that gives your columns proper names? Or give them better names to start with. I have been working with relational databases for over 30 year now and I never had any situation where I would need something like this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name n=1. To each, his own. In my case, I can't just go changing names willy nilly as I'm not the only person depending on these column names. Views are a good solution to many problems. This just seems so fundamental that I puzzle pondering why it's not solved in the database. Looked at another way, I don't understand why I should solve the disambiguation problem as a user of the database when the database has a completely disambiguated view of the namespace in the first place.